# FFMPEG mic recording seems to have an automatic gain function

Tags: ffmpeg, microphone

`ffmpeg -y -f dshow -rtbufsize 10M -i audio=%mic% -f dshow -rtbufsize 10M -i audio="Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)" -init_hw_device d3d11va -filter_complex ddagrab=video_size=1280x720:offset_x=1200:offset_y=100 -c:v h264_nvenc -qp 0 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2 vidaud.mp4`

1. I'm using this command to record from a mic, system sound and desktop as video on Windows 10
2. My recording sounds as though it has an automatic gain function, as in the noise gets louder and louder during periods of silence
3. From testing with other apps, e.g. audacity, whatsapp in chrome, I don't get that same behavior when recording, i.e. noise remains constant
4. Thus, I'm assuming it is coming from FFMPEG, any idea how to disable it? Or where does it come from?